# RXJS from() doesn't execute within concatMap()

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, jasmine

I am trying to run a test with Jasmine to click a button which copies a value to the clipboard. I'm then trying to read the value that was saved in the clipboard.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here, but the output that I am getting in the console is this:

```
timer 1
```

What I am expecting to see in the console is this:

```
timer 1
read
timer 2
```

The Jasmine code that I am using looks like this:

```js
  it('should copy input value', () => {
    const click = component.clickButton('buttonElRef');
    click.subscribe(value => {
      console.log('v', value);
    });
  });
```

The Angular test component looks like this:

```js
class CopyToClipboardTest {
  clickButton(which: 'buttonObjRef' | 'buttonElRef'): Observable<string> {
    this[which].nativeElement.click();
    return timer(100).pipe(
      tap(() => console.log('timer 1')),
      concatMap(() => this.getClipboard()),
      tap(() => console.log('timer 2')),
    );
  }

  getClipboard(): Observable<string> {
    return from(navigator.clipboard.readText()).pipe(tap(() => console.log('read')));
  }
}
```

Comment: Does navigator exist within your jasmine test environment? What happens if there is an error within concatMap()? you might have to mock navigator.clipboard.readText()

Comment: `console.log('readText' in navigator.clipboard)` prints `true`.

Comment: This works: `return from(Promise.resolve('Hello World'));`

Comment: Ok seems that the readText() promise never resolves. Maybe try a console log in the then() callback from readText()

Comment: Or it is a async problem. Did you try using fakeAsync for this?

Comment: Looks like your right, `navigator.clipboard.readText().then(() => console.log('hi'))` never prints

Comment: Randomly my chrome test window decided to show a "Allow Access to Clipboard" window. Giving the browser access allowed the clipboard to finally execute. However, it still doesn't run the `then()` from time to time.

Comment: @SirOneOfMany So, it looks like the error that I am getting is that is causing it to not run is: `DOMException: Document is not focused.`

Answer (score 0):

So, when using the clipboard you need to give the window focus before executing clipboard events.

This fixes the issue (it doesn't seem to work on auto reload though):

```js
beforeAll(() => window.focus());
```